# Fixing a broken hard drive's partition map

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a drive that is corrupted. Disk utility could not repair the disk, so I attempted to follow some tutorials and repair the partitions using pdisk and testdisk, but things have gone south. Now the drive no longer shows up at all in Disk Utility, and diskutil info gives this output:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk1
Device Identifier:        
Device Node:              
Part of Whole:            
Device / Media Name:      

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Partition Type:           None
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               
Protocol:                 

Total Size:               0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)

Read-Only Media:          Yes
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
Ejectable:                No

Whole:                    No
Internal:                 No
```

This is a 3TB external Seagate drive. Is there anything I can do, or is this drive a paperweight? At this point I don't even care about the data on the drive. I just want to know if it can be reformatted and be usable, or if I need to go out and get a new drive.

Comment: I'd say, the more you keep doing to break it, the less chance you'll have of recovering it. Concentrate on getting data off, if it's not backed up; otherwise just format it...

Comment: @Tetsujin Well I tried to format it, but diskutil gives me a "this is not a whole disk" error. It doesn't even show up in the GUI.

Comment: might be the enclosure - have you another to try? If it's a USB, you can't check smart, though if you've a Mac Pro etc you could move it to internal to check that

Comment: @Tetsujin This is the only enclosure that I have. I do have a Mac Pro, but I have the trashcan one. There are no drive bays :P

Comment: @Tetsujin I do have several PCs that I could put it in. I could try that and attempt to reformat it to NTFS.

Comment: ah… knew there was a reason I don't have one of those yet … aside from I can't afford one yet ;)  & yup - if you don't care about the data, try a PC

Comment: @Tetsujin Alright well I do have a copy of DiskWarrior at home. I'll give that a shot, and if that doesn't work, I'll attempt to format it on a PC.

Comment: Wish you luck...

Comment: It might be useful if you can give the model of the drive. Also, if you put the drive in an enclosure, give that model also. I an wondering if being a 3 TB  drive means you have a 4096 byte sector  size.

Comment: @DavidAnderson It's actually an external hard drive. It is a seagate 3TB external (I know, seagate...) and it does have a 4096 sector size.

Comment: I did not realize until now that I helped you back in February. Is this the same disk?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Fortunately (well sort of, depending on the way you look at it), this is not the same drive. For whatever reason, the partition on the drive became inaccessible, and so I tried to repair it using the same method as before, but I screwed something up along the way and here I am.

Comment: When you plug this disk into the USB port, does anything appear in the Disk Utility application? How did you know it was disk1 when using the Terminal application?

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I used testdisk to determine that

Answer (score 3):

For the reference of others: if you're absolutely sure it's the partition map that's damaged, **after backing up the drive** you could use fdisk in a Linux virtual machine to verify it. Something like `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` and then v verifies the partition map. You could recreate the partition map manually too with fdisk or gparted, without actually erasing anything.

William T Froggard fails to mention in his answer that repartitioning with disk utility will almost always be destructive, unless you're resizing a HFS+/APFS disk.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried asking disk utility to redo the partition map? Click on the disk, go into the "partition" tab, set it from "Current" to "1 Partition", click "Options", change the partition table to anything else, then repeat the process and set it back. If the issue is the partition table, that will fix it. If the issue is the drive, then it won't. Either way, you'll have your answer.

Comment: Is this destructive of the data on the disk? The blurb on that tab says "To erase and partition the selected disk, choose a layout from the Partition Layout pop-up menu, set options for each partition, and click Apply." That sounds destructive to me.

Comment: It is destructive. I mentioned this as a last resort for someone who can't use the disk at all.